# Agora ui kit not working flutter. rtc engine error

Tags: flutter, agora

Launching lib\main.dart on 2201117TI in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.3.7/lib/models/agora_rtc_event_handlers.dart:189:7: Error: Type 'LocalVideoStreamError' not found.
LocalVideoStreamError error)? onLocalVideoStateChanged;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.3.7/lib/models/agora_rtc_event_handlers.dart:354:40: Error: Type 'RhythmPlayerErrorType' not found.
RhythmPlayerStateType state, RhythmPlayerErrorType errorCode)?
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.3.7/lib/models/agora_rtc_event_handlers.dart:446:7: Error: Type 'LocalAudioStreamError' not found.
LocalAudioStreamError error)? onLocalAudioStateChanged;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.3.7/lib/models/agora_rtc_event_handlers.dart:521:7: Error: Type 'RtmpStreamPublishErrorType' not found.
RtmpStreamPublishErrorType errCode)? onRtmpStreamingStateChanged;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.3.7/lib/models/agora_rtc_event_handlers.dart:554:23: Error: Type 'ChannelMediaRelayEvent' not found.
final void Function(ChannelMediaRelayEvent code)? onChannelMediaRelayEvent;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.3.7/lib/models/agora_rtc_event_handlers.dart:189:7: Error: 'LocalVideoStreamError' isn't a type.
LocalVideoStreamError error)? onLocalVideoStateChanged;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.3.7/lib/models/agora_rtc_event_handlers.dart:354:40: Error: 'RhythmPlayerErrorType' isn't a type.
RhythmPlayerStateType state, RhythmPlayerErrorType errorCode)?
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.3.7/lib/models/agora_rtc_event_handlers.dart:446:7: Error: 'LocalAudioStreamError' isn't a type.
LocalAudioStreamError error)? onLocalAudioStateChanged;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.3.7/lib/models/agora_rtc_event_handlers.dart:521:7: Error: 'RtmpStreamPublishErrorType' isn't a type.
RtmpStreamPublishErrorType errCode)? onRtmpStreamingStateChanged;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.3.7/lib/models/agora_rtc_event_handlers.dart:554:23: Error: 'ChannelMediaRelayEvent' isn't a type.
final void Function(ChannelMediaRelayEvent code)? onChannelMediaRelayEvent;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.3.7/lib/controllers/rtc_event_handlers.dart:146:6: Error: No named parameter with the name 'onChannelMediaRelayEvent'.
}, onChannelMediaRelayEvent: (code) {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_rtc_engine-6.3.0/lib/src/agora_rtc_engine.dart:1576:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
const RtcEngineEventHandler({
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\kgour\Downloads\flutter_windows_3.19.1-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

**Here is the code where i have used agora ui kit.**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:agora_uikit/agora_uikit.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class VideoCallScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  const VideoCallScreen({Key? key}): super(key: key);

  @override
  State<VideoCallScreen> createState() => _VideoCallScreenState();
}

class _VideoCallScreenState extends State<VideoCallScreen>{
  final AgoraClient _client = AgoraClient(agoraConnectionData: AgoraConnectionData(
    appId: '305587582691460b8345fcdb4542463b',
    channelName: 'fluttering',
    tempToken: '007',
  ),);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initAgora();
  }

  Future<void>_initAgora() async{
    await _client.initialize();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text('Video Call'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            AgoraVideoViewer(client: _client, layoutType: Layout.floating, showNumberOfUsers: true,),
            AgoraVideoButtons(client: _client, enabledButtons: [
              BuiltInButtons.toggleCamera,
              BuiltInButtons.callEnd,
              BuiltInButtons.toggleMic,
            ],),
          ],
        ),

      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).